# Python + Neural Nets + Large dimension Large Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

I am building a NLP application. My dataset has 0.6M datapoints each of 0.15M dimensions. My feature vector is highly sparse - mostly 0s, atmost 20 1s in any feature vector. I am using a 32 GB machine on AWS.

Owing to size, Cant load entire dataset in one go in the memory. **I am looking for a python based neural net library that supports** (if not all then atleast some) of the following [Owing to the dataset size and dimension, i defined below mentioned abilities]:

1. Ability to train the net on small batches
2. library being able to exploit underlying multicore architecture (if available)
3. A way to directly feed the feature vectors in compressed representation (like scipy.sparse) [in my case

I have had a good look at the following libraries - **PyBrain, Pylearn2, NeuroLab, FANN**. To the best of my understanding, none of them has any of the desired abilities (Pybrain facilitates batch leaning. Even this takes close to 55 hrs).

Any suggestions ? (cant reduce dimentionality)  Or in case *there is a shortcoming in my understanding and the any of the above libraries have (some) above capabilities*, can you pls point out me to some sample code implementing/exploiting the same ?

Comment: You can use Theano backend to implement your own neural net. It will take advantage of multiple CPUs or GPUs

Comment: @Betrand: I agree, but in theano can I run learning in batches and directly feed compressed representation ?

Comment: Since you have to implement your own network then you can do whatever you want about batches as long as the learning process isn't harmed. About compressed representation I don't think it can be handled, but if I were you, my main concern would be the dimension of the input space which seems to be way too huge to learn anything meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented with PyBrain and PyLearn2
I rather find Keras [http://keras.io/ ] as an excellent choice. It way ahead of PyBrain for sure. PyBrain development has been stopped